# Shared element transition in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use shared element transition on RecyclerView but it doesn't seem to work.

This is a part of my adapter in which I use `makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final BookViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity)context , holder.smallThumbnail, "thumbnailTransition");
                context.startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: also add the code of your DetailsActivity

Comment: you can look at this tutorial once https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/shared-element-activity-transition

Comment: @vinayManeti It looks to be the same code except there it is used in an activity and I'm using it in an adapter.

Comment: @user3333848 There is nothing in DetailsActivity relating to transitions. I'm just displaying an ImageView there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your Adapter

```
holder.smallThumbnail.setTransitionName("thumbnailTransition");
Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create((View) holder.smallThumbnail, holder.smallThumbnail.getTransitionName());

ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) mContext, pair1, pair2);
mContext.startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

> In Your Detail Activity

```
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transation));
mainImage.setTransitionName("thumbnailTransition");
```

Here this mainimage is imageview where you want to transform your previous activity thumbnail

> shared_element_transation  create one xml in res>transition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500">
<changeBounds />
<fade />
</transitionSet>
```

Comment: I'm getting a ClassCastException at `(Activity) mContext` saying "Application cannot be cast to Activity"

Comment: use activity context may be you are passing application context to adapter or 2nd way is make callback interface and do code in activity

Comment: How do I pass an activity context instead of an application context?

Comment: insted of getApplicationContex() use ActvityName.this when you pass context to adapter

Comment: what is the pair2?

Answer (score 0):

**WITH PICASSO**

> Adapter

```
holder.smallImageView.setTransitionName("transition_name");
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, holder.smallImageView, "transition_name");

Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

---

> DetailActivity

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .into(bigImageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            bigImageView.setTransitionName("transition_name");
            getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
```

---

> res/transition/shared_element_transition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500">
    <changeBounds />
    <fade />
</transitionSet>
```